# Что может крутого сделать React.js чего не может jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Всегда писал на jQuery. Но вот недавно сделал хелло ворлд на AngularJS, Angular2, React.js, Vue.js. И честно говоря не нашел в них ничего супер крутого. Скажите, пожалуйста, лучше с реальным примером — где jQuery проигрывает ReactJS. Желательно в связке с asp.net mvc/api

Comment: В хелло ворлде вы вряд ли найдёте разницу. Это так же как Rx в Java - проявляется в крупных и сложных проектах

Comment: Всегда катался на пони. Но вот недавно решил прокатиться на беговой/гужевой лошадях в вальере 2х2, и честно говоря не нашел в них ничего супер крутого. Скажите пожалуйста, лучше с реальным примером - где пони проигрывают лошади? Желательно в связке со стойлом.

Comment: Всё, что угодно, может сделать и чистый JS — все варианты полны по Тьюрингу, а значит, равносильны. Вопрос лишь в удобстве.

Comment: С начало узнайте в чем разница между библиотекой и фреймворком.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

В реакте другой подход к рендерингу интерфейса. Как любят говорить, интерфейс становится функцией от состояния. Вот это и есть круто. Накручивать реакт на мвц-модель на фронтенде я бы не стал (хотя долго пытался сделать это в связке с mobx). Одним днём, разбираясь с react-apollo (graphql клиент) мне открылось оно - react composition. В этот день, после более года работы с реактом, я, как мне кажется, действительно понял, что такое реакт.

Реакт позволяет абстрагироваться от DOM и в этом большой плюс. Тестировать значительно проще.

Важно понять, что мы входим (русское сообщество ещё, судя по всему, входит, а мировое уже вошло) в эпоху компонентного веба. jquery в него не вписывается. Не зря гугл пропагандирует свои WebComponents. На данный момент это, кажется, ещё более экспериментальная вещь. Тем не менее, однозначно можно сказать, что компонентам быть, а дёрганию дома селекторами не быть.

Реакт становится многократно лучше со следующими технологиями (без них, я бы сказал, бессмысленно его трогать):

0) (от xFloooo) `react-loadable` упрощает асинхронную подгрузку кода (code-splitting)

1) `es6/typescript/flow`. Лично я бы порекомендовал Typescript, т.к. библиотека типов значительно больше. Некоторые из них, к сожалению, не всегда оправдываю ожидания полностью, но в целом всё работает довольно хорошо. Наверное, не в strict режиме, дабы не играть в игру "убедим тайпскрипт, что наш код правильно написан).

Использование типизированного языка многократно облегчает задачу дебага реакт-компонентов, в ситуациях когда пропсы перебрасываются от одного компонента к другому, что может повторятся несколько раз подряд. тайпскрипт или флоу сразу же подскажут, какие пропсы поступают в неверном типе. Причём этот типа может быть не только простым скалярным, но и сложным интерфейсом.

2) `storybook` - чтобы работать над презентационными компонентами в вакууме (а не пытаться их сразу встроить в сайт). Это виртуальное полотно, где мы можем разместить компонент, над которым работаем и смотреть как он себя ведёт и программировать его. И подключать в проект, когда компонент написан, а не в процессе написания.

3) `redux/mobx`. рекомендую редакс, в основном из-за большой экосистемы и прозрачности работы. `typescript-fsa` - полностью типизированные экшны!

4) `react-router` и `react-redux-router` - практически безальтернативное решение маршрутизации в приложении

4) `recompose` и паттерны `hoc/react-composition/render props`

5) `styled-components` + `polished` или, возможно, css-in-js типа `aphrodite`

6) `jest` для тестирования (вы же пишете тесты?)

7) Для redux-а существует большое количество библиотек, из них я бы хотел выделить

`redux-form` для форм

`redux-fractal` / `redux-ui` для локального стейта контейнеров (можно с лёгкостью использовать копии одного и того же стора (стейт/экшены/редьюсеры) для нескольких контейнеров.

Ну и в довесок:

`react-semantic-ui` для прототипирования интерфейсов (а может и для продакшна, если настроить dead code elimination). Конечно же, это не единственная библиотека подобного характера, есть ещё `antd`, `react-material-ui`и дюжина других. Тот же бутстрап

`react-sortable-hoc` для быстрого dnd в рамках одного списка

`classnames` - швейцарский нож для соединения многих имён css классов в одну строку, когда присутствует сложная логика

Что вспомню - допишу

Comment: забыл, соус для всего этого - VIM

Comment: Спасибо за списочек. Я тоже пишу на React, но не очень долго, где-то 3-4 месяца, и интересно какие ещё фишки на нём применяются. И я кстати использую React + MobX + TypeScript на ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC, хотя сам MVC мне особо не нужен по причинам однастраничности

Comment: Фишек, по-видимому, много. Иногда натыкаюсь на гитхабе на какой-нибудь проект (не обяз. про реакт) с 15-20 тыс. звёзд и думаю - а где же я был? На медиуме много пишут, но когда же за всем уследить.

Есть такая фишка на гитхабе - `awesome-X`, где вместо X подставляется любая библиотека/технология и т.д., к примеру awesome-redux, awesome-styled-components - в этих репозитория собирают ссылки на качественные (не всегда) связанные проекты

Comment: да, немешало бы мне посмотреть хороший код на React... только время не хочется тратить, хочется писать уже ))

Comment: Да я тоже полюбил читать исходники на гитхабе. Будут интересные ссылки - сброшу тут

Comment: кстати, это очень знакомое чувство "хочется писать" =D

Comment: Всё хорошо описано, я бы посоветовал обязательно попробовать mobx.
Так же в список надо внести react-loadable.

Comment: mobx хороший, работал с ним около года, но познакомившись (т.е. наконеу-то найдя время нормально разобраться) с редаксом, у меня упала челюсть - количество отличных библиотек и простота реализации комплексной логики удивили. Наверное я работал с мобх неправильно, пытаясь наворачивать некий mvc на нем. В итоге переписал весь  текущий проект :) а react-loadable посмотрю что за зверь.

Comment: а список уже есть! https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, как раз в следующем проекте надо будет делать кож-сплиттинг, и, надеюсь, уже скоро