# Какой выбрать js-фреймворк для разработки?

Tags: javascript, framework

В последнее время, я все чаще задумываюсь прекратить использование JQuery, и посмотреть в сторону какого-нибудь js фреймворка. Много читал, что JQuery потихоньку переходит в прошлое. В связи с этим несколько вопросов:

в1. Стоит ли уходить от jquery?
в2. Если в1 = true, то какой фреймворк лучше использовать?

Спасибо всем за ваши ответы!

Comment: (имхо) Vue.js, React, Angular, Elm, ... - почитайте про всё, изучите пару, хотя бы один React

Comment: Смотря для каких целей и какой проект. Иногда кроме чистого ничего больше и не надо. Для одностраничных приложений я бы посоветовал vue.js

Comment: Очень удачно я нашел.Десятка самых популярных фреймворков для JavaScript.
Рекомендую к прочтению: https://use-web.ru/news.php?id=59&tid=2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### JQuery

Большая часть функциональности которая в своё время была прорывом и очень нужна, сейчас есть в чистом javascript. Поэтому всё больше программистов, и я тоже, уходят с JQuery на чистый Javascript.

Приведу пару примеров.

**Селекторы** - основа JQuery сейчас нативно поддерживаются Javascript.

**jquery.ajax** - сейчас появилась функция fetch, которая очень удобно умеет работать асинхронно на основе промисов, и в ней так же учтены многие другие пожелания программистов, а некоторые фичи ещё ждут своей имплементации внутри неё.

### Другие фреймворки

Они нужны, но их использование зависит от задачи.
Что бы понять изучать их или нет, стоит хотя бы кратко посмотреть, почитать что они могут делать, про каждый в отдельности. И, конечно не обязательно все сразу, для начала можно наиболее популярные.

И да, например React рассматривать как замену JQuery никак нельзя этот фреймворк совсем с другими задачами, другие фреймворки тоже. То есть их надо рассматривать не как замену, но зависит от задачи, например в случае React это может быть платформа для приложения + стиль программирования, кодирования.

Приведу пример.

Сарай не заменяет баню, а баня не заменяет дом. Нужно знать зачем они нужны, и исходя из этого принимать решение.

Comment: (+) Но думаю больше плюсов соберёте, если будут хоть краткие примеры кода использования JS вместо JQuery и не совсем понятно из ответа, почему он так резко разонравился, достукавшись до разных обидных прозвищ :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Меня как раз таки интересовала реализация ajax/его аналоги в других фреймворках, но раз уж вы сказали, что теперь она есть в javascript - буду заучивать его)

Comment: Дмитрий, но jquery - это набор функций, который были призваны упростить жизнь js-программисту. Фреймворком (то есть определённой стукрутированной базой для выполнения работы) это назвать нельзя, так как никакой структуры jquery не предлагает. И в этом его самая большая проблема, как орудия привития плохих привычек. Можно чуть более подробно уточнить, что есть этим "совсем другие задачи", которые призван решить jquery в противовес реакту? Спасибо!

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko JQuery очевидно не идёт в противовес реакту, он (Jquery) сам по себе уже отпадает, именно это я и писал в своём сообщение, а сравнивать предлагаю актуальные Framework-и, например React, Angular, Vue итп.

Comment: @YuriGo `jQuery` не фреймворк вовсе - это раз. Во вторых `React, Angular, Vue` и иже с ними сильно убирают гибкость разработки, понижают удобство отладки, понижают производительность, и главное - усложняют разработку, повышают её стоимость в разы. Поэтому радикально не согласен с мнением автора ответа, такие советы могут убить стартап. Что даёт jquery - и не даёт встроенный функционал: это цепочка вызовов, здравствуй ФП! Не говорю уже о всяческих общепринятых утилитах вроде, `.animate`, `.slideToggle`. Недаром `50%` сайтов в мире обладают jQuery, он практически неразрывен с образом самого `JS`

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что jQuery это фреймворк. Вопрос был в том, на какой фреймворк уйти с jQuery, и надо ли вообще это делать.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр React тоже не фреймворк. Фреймворки усложняют разработку только маленьких сайтов, а серьезные решения фреймворк упрощают разрабатывать, помогают структурировать код

Comment: @Alex78191 согласно определению википедии react можно считать фреймворком - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фреймворк , согласно официальной документации библиотека. Но с другой стороны никто не говорит что одно отрицает другое, то что официально он назван библиотекой не говорит о том что он не является фреймворком. Но вот что jQuery не фреймворк, тут я думаю однозначно да. Если интересно, можно эту тему обсудить в отдельном вопросе.

Comment: @Alex78191 не стал бы утверждать столь однозначно, поэтому и прокомментировал - потому что многие, по моим наблюдениям, иногда выключают голову и ведутся на тренд: что использовать JS-фреймворки круто. Серьёзные решения натыкаются постоянно на то что фреймворки усложняют их разработку, так как нельзя использовать фрейм только когда этого требует отдельная страница(иначе код будет ужасен). Структурировать в серьёзном решении нечего на фронтенде - так как в серьёзном решении хорошо организован бекенд (вот там как-раз без фрейма никуда). Поэтому для справедливости выражаю свою позицию.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Я не согласен, что структурировать во Frontend разработке нечего. Слой представления как сервисный слой и слой бизнес-логики нуждается в структурировании.

Comment: @Alex78191 нуждается, но если есть MVC на бекенде - часто достаточно структурирование подключаемыми скриптами, из конкретных экшенов(контроллеров) - то есть через файловую систему разбиение. Контент самих таких скриптов - разумеется в замыкание завёрнут. Конечно бывает что-то общее на всю систему -  но фреймворк для этого общего избыточен как правило. Лично не против фреймворков - но очень не понравилось однобокое освещение вопроса, если уж обсуждают такие сложные темы без однозначного ответа - извольте осветить все плюсы и минусы разных подходов, иначе попортите мозги новичков!

Answer (score 1):

Стоит стоит, если не хотите быть выброшенным с корабля фронтенд вебдева. Также, я уверен, что в скором времени писать нетипизированный js станет плохим тоном. В выборе между flow и typescript последний определённо далеко впереди.

Относительно реакта..  реакт меняет мышление и подход к разработке приложения и сближает нас с концепциями функционального программирования. Реакт - это захватывающее путешествие через джунгли современного джаваскрипта. В том числе и потому, что Реакт по сути только рендерит функции в dom, и не предлагает ничего более. Вот здесь я привёл список основных вкусностей, которые превращают разработку проекта с реактом в прогулку по осеннему лесу: [Что может крутого сделать React.js чего не может jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762093/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-react-js-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-jquery/762591#762591)

Все современные фреймворки/библиотеки (angular, vue, react, svetle, riot, polymer, aurelia), все являются компонентно-ориентированными и именно компонентно-ориентированный подход становится (или уже стал?) стандартом в разработке веб-приложений. Поэтому императивный стиль jquery (в духе "выберем ноду из дома по id, зададим ей класс, приаттачим ещё пару нод, запустим анимацию через встроенную функцию animate и в конце сделаем .show() если выполняется условие и всё это назовём function showNewComment()", к счастью, остаётся в прошлом.

Через какое-то время создание функционального веб-приложения будет возможно путём накидывания изолированных компонентов в визуальном редакторе. Компонентом будет всё от лэйоута сайта до формы регистрации.

Конечно, для того, что принято называть "сайт-визитка", никакой фреймворк не нужен. Но мы же говорим про что-то более сложное, да?

И в качестве ещё одного доказательства, что стоит учить реакт (или ангуляр): какая прорывная технология для фронтеда за последние несколько лет не имеет реакт- или ангуляр-библиотеки или не связана с ними компонентно-ориентированным базисом?

P.S. https://codesandbox.io/ здесь можно начать изучение реакта и других фреймворков без предварительной подготовки окружения разработки на локальной машине

Comment: Для меня важно, чтобы в библиотеке/фреймворке была возможность выполнять запросы без перезагрузки страницы (как ajax). Но, с другой стороны, я понимаю, что jquery (возможно) теряет свои позиции, не говоря уже о его развитии. Поэтому хочется найти что-то похожее по возможностям, опять же типа ajax, но более современное.

Comment: Это очень хорошо, такая возможность, такая возможность предоставляется любым браузером. jquery - лишь одна из обёрток для XHR (XmlHttpRequest). Одна из популярных реализация называется fetch api.. но в общем это имеет мало отношения к указанным фреймворкам, они про другое..

Comment: (+) согласен, что сейчас всё идёт и уже есть к компонентной разработке, и сам как раз использую React + typescript. Можно подумать как общий вопрос задать по поводу новых тенденций в веб и фронтенд, и можно будет на него популярно ответить.

Comment: Typescript это наверное лучшее, что случалось с js со времён node.js. Когда приходится писать на чистом js, его ужасно не хватает..

Comment: С другой стороны, не один час был потрачен на игру в "заставь эти типы из @types работать", а также на игру в "strict и только strict". Особенно типы для redux-form расстраивают, но это временно надеюсь.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы, основываясь на своём личном опыте работы с указанными фреймворкам, советовал вам сначала изучить работу с Angular/Vue, после чего приступать к React, в связи с тем, что Angular легко изучить чем React. После того как изучите Ангуляр на отлично, приступите к React

Comment: Я бы, основываясь на своём личном опыте работы с указанными фреймворкам, советовал вам сначала изучить работу с Angular/Vue, после чего приступать к React, в связи с тем, что ....

Comment: Да, я бы тоже так сказал